# How to set oh-my-fish theme

Tags: fish

I have installed oh-my-fish and bobthefish them, I want to use `bobthefish` theme, I follow his advise and put `Theme bobthefish` in my `~/.config/fish/config.fish` and run `omf install`, but it report a bug:

```
fish: Unknown command 'Theme bobthefish'
~/.config/fish/config.fish (line 19): Theme bobthefish
                                      ^
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
    called during startup
```

This is my `config.fish`:

```
# Path to your oh-my-fish.
set -g OMF_PATH $HOME/.local/share/omf

# Path to your oh-my-fish configuration.
set -g OMF_CONFIG $HOME/.config/omf

fish_vi_mode
set --export EDITOR "vim"


### Configuration required to load oh-my-fish ###
# Note: Only add configurations that are required to be set before oh-my-fish is loaded.
# For common configurations, we advise you to add them to your $OMF_CONFIG/init.fish file or
# to create a custom plugin instead.

# Load oh-my-fish configuration.
source $OMF_PATH/init.fish

Theme bobthefish
```

Answer (score 6):

I am one of the contributors of Oh My Fish.

I highly recommend you upgrading from previous version by doing a clean install. Please follow the upgrade instructions present on Oh My Fish repository's README file.

After a clean install it's just a matter of issuing an `omf install bobthefish` and you will be into the theme.

If you still need help feel free to join our Slack and raise your voice!

Answer (score 1):

If you are still using an older version of oh-my-fish, you have to use " around the theme name.

For newer version, you can follow the [recommended upgrade path that oh-my-fish provides](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish/issues/33#issuecomment-138925098):

1. **BACKUP ALL YOUR CUSTOM STUFF**
2. `mv ~/.config/fish/config{,_old}.fish`
3. `rm -rf ~/.oh-my-fish`
4. Do a clean Oh My Fish install
5. Copy all lines starting with `Plugin` and `Theme` from `~/.config/fish/config_old.fish`
6. Paste them it into `$OMF_CONFIG/bundle` file. If it doesn't exist, create it
7. Convert all `Plugin "name"` lines to `package name`
8. Convert all `Theme "name"` lines to `theme name`
9. `omf install`

So, to sum up, if you want to install a theme with this newer version, you need to put `theme bobthefish` in your `~/.config/omf/bundle` file.

Comment: It fails. `fish: Unknown command 'Theme bobthefish'
~/.config/fish/config.fish (line 18): Theme "bobthefish"
                                      ^
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
 called during startup` . And if I use `omf theme bobthefish`, it just says `bobthefish theme up to data`

Comment: You are correct, it seems that they changed the system yesterday - I upgraded oh-my-fish on my system and had the same error. I have updated my answer to reflect this change.

Comment: I install oh-my-fish today from github

Comment: Then you can follow the updated instructions I posted

Comment: I follow your instruction. My `$OMF_CONFIG/bundle` now have `theme bobthefish`, but it doesn't do antthing.

Comment: i have the same problem after upgrade, even doing the above instructions.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

https://github.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish/wiki/FAQ#i-changed-my-prompt-with-fish_config-and-now-i-cant-get-my-oh-my-fish-themes-prompt-back-what-do-i-do

From oh-my-fish slack forum, its just to remove the fish_promt default file.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Put file in `~/.config/fish/conf.d/my-theme.conf` to load `Seaweed` theme:

```
fish_config theme choose Seaweed
```